# How to Enable or Disable the buttons in JavaFX form?

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on my project and there are some buttons that I wanted to disable at the time of running. So I disabled them but How can I enable them back when I wanted to.?? Because there is no `setEnable()` property.

Please tell me how can I enable the buttons?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [`disableProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty--):

> Defines the individual disabled state of this Node. Setting disable to
>   true will cause this Node and any subnodes to become disabled. This
>   property should be used only to set the disabled state of a Node. For
>   querying the disabled state of a Node, the disabled property should
>   instead be used, since it is possible that a Node was disabled as a
>   result of an ancestor being disabled even if the individual disable
>   state on this Node is false.

```
setDisable(true); // will disable the Button
setDisable(false); // will enable it again
```

Comment: Thanks sir. I have one more question. Suppose I have a disable button at the time of running and I have some Text Fields in that particular form. what I want is. IF text fields are filled with some kind of data then and then only the button should be enable otherwise it has be disabled. Sir Please tell me how can do it.

Comment: It should be asked in a separate question, but well. Imagine you have 2 `TextField`s `tf1` and `tf2` and a `Button`. Then `button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding( () ->
                        !(tf1.getText().contains("A") && tf2.getText().contains("B"))
        , tf1.textProperty(), tf2.textProperty()));` will cause the button to be enabled if the first text field contains an "A" character and the second one contains a "B" character. The button is disabled otherwise.

Comment: sorry sir. but I am not able to post a question because I am new here. so only allowing me to ask limited questions.

Comment: sorry to say sir but what u have replied I didn't understand anything. can you give me proper code.PLEASE